# How I can give fifteen seconds of delay?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

My program loads the user's current position via GPS and save it in a txt file to send by email for statistical purposes. my problems is:

- first attempt to give you 15 seconds delay every time it save a position with:

  `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15.0 target:self selector:@selector(locationManager:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

the problem is that this doesn't work and doesn't know what is the reason for it.

- my other problem is: if the file is too big... for that I want to name the date of the day which was created and a different one every day. I tried several things but I have not gotten anything.

the code:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

//Obtenemos las coordenadas.
latitud = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
longitud = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
precision = newLocation.horizontalAccuracy;

// Lo mostramos en las etiquetas
[latitudLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.8f",latitud]];
[longitudLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.8f",longitud]];
[precisionLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.8f",precision]];
tiempoLabel=[self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:newLocation.timestamp];
//NSLog(@"tiempo: %@",tiempoLabel);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"textfile.txt"];
//[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];

// create if needed
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]){
    [[NSData data] writeToFile:path atomically:YES];}

NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tiempo: %@ latitude:%+.6f longitude: %+.6f precisión: %f\n",tiempoLabel,latitud,longitud,precision];

NSFileHandle *handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
[handle truncateFileAtOffset:[handle seekToEndOfFile]];    
[handle writeData:[contents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];}
```

thanks for the help. StackOverflow has helped me a lot with my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You raise two different issues:

1. Regarding your timer, do you have a method called `locationManager:`? You haven't shown that method, so it looks highly suspect. If you're trying to call your `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`, that won't work. The `@selector` for the `NSTimer` must have not more than one parameter. You can write a simple timer handler method that calls whatever method you want, e.g.

   ```
   - (void)handleTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
   {
       // call whatever method you want here
   }
   ```

   Then you can do:

   ```
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15.0 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
   ```

   Note, repeating timers can cause retain cycles, so if you ever plan on dismissing this at some point, you might want to keep a reference to the timer so you can `invalidate` it later (such as in `viewDidDisappear`).

   Having said that, I agree with the counsel to not write every 15 seconds, but rather I'd use the [`desiredAccuracy`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW18) and [`distanceFilter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW3) to control when the location manager delegate method is called. Logging locations every *x* seconds is a great way to crush a user's battery. For other battery saving guidance, see [Tips for Conserving Battery](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW17) in the *Location Awareness Programming Guide.*
2. On your second problem,

   - you don't need to do that "create if needed" code; and
   - when writing the file, you don't need that `NSFileHandle` code; you can just use the `NSString` instance method [`writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJDIDCE) (which, by the way, includes a `NSError` parameter that you can examine if the file writing doesn't succeed).

Comment: Thank you very much. help me very much. now i try to clear the text file with`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];` but i dont know if it is the correct.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to ditch the timer and go with checking for a certain amount of accuracy, here is some sample code of checking gps accuracy which would need to be modified or take a line or two from it for your needs

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    // test the age of the location measurement to determine if the measurement is cached
    // in most cases you will not want to rely on cached measurements
    NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];

    if (locationAge > 5.0) return;

    // test that the horizontal accuracy does not indicate an invalid measurement
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) return;

    // test the measurement to see if it is more accurate than the previous measurement
    if (bestEffortAtLocation == nil || bestEffortAtLocation.horizontalAccuracy > newLocation.horizontalAccuracy) {
        // store the location as the "best effort"
        self.bestEffortAtLocation = newLocation;

        // test the measurement to see if it meets the desired accuracy
        //
        // IMPORTANT!!! kCLLocationAccuracyBest should not be used for comparison with location coordinate or altitidue 
        // accuracy because it is a negative value. Instead, compare against some predetermined "real" measure of 
        // acceptable accuracy, or depend on the timeout to stop updating. This sample depends on the timeout.
        //
        if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= locationManager.desiredAccuracy) {
            // we have a measurement that meets our requirements, so we can stop updating the location
            // 
            // IMPORTANT!!! Minimize power usage by stopping the location manager as soon as possible.
            //
            [self stopUpdatingLocation:NSLocalizedString(@"Acquired Location", @"Acquired Location")];

            // we can also cancel our previous performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: - it's no longer necessary
            [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(stopUpdatingLocation:) object:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

as for the file with date im confused by the naming issue i would assume a number format for title would work out fine for your needs.Though looking at your code you need to seperate a lot of what is going on from your didUpdateLocation method because this will be called every few seconds on average and that creates a lot of issues without telling your program to wait or do not update file again until a certain point.